# Nested while loop not working in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to succeed with project euler's 4th problem : *What is the biggest palindrome-number you can make by multiplying 2 3-digit numbers ?*
( https://projecteuler.net/problem=4 )

I have the following code but it is not working. For some reason it seems like the nested while loop is broken. It only print numbers 10000 to 99900, which means the nested while loop is executed only once...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int is_a_palindrome(int test_number);

int main (void)
{
    long     result;
    long     number_x_1;
    long     number_x_2;
    long    biggest_pal;

    number_x_1 = 100;
    number_x_2 = 100;

    while (number_x_1 < 1000)
    {
        while (number_x_2 < 1000)
        {
            result = number_x_1 * number_x_2;
            printf("%li\n", result);
            if (is_a_palindrome(result) == 1)
            {
                biggest_pal = result;
                printf("palindrome found : %li", biggest_pal);
            }
            number_x_2++;
        }
    number_x_1++;
    }
    return (biggest_pal);
}

int is_a_palindrome(int test_number)
{
    int test_number_unchanged;
    int reverse;

    reverse = 0;
    test_number_unchanged = test_number;

   while (test_number != 0)
    {
      reverse = reverse * 10;
      reverse = reverse + test_number % 10;
      test_number = test_number / 10;
    }

    if (test_number_unchanged == reverse)
    {
        return (1);
    }
    else
    {
        return (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reset 'number_x_2' back to 100 within the first while loop

Comment: How about resetting the `number_x_2`, once the inner loop is done?

Comment: If you had stepped through this with your debugger, the bug would have been immediately obvious:((

Comment: Aren't these challenge sites supposed to test your good self?

Comment: thanks to all, I'm sorry the answer seems so obvious now. I did use my debugger :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set number_x_2 to 100 inside the outer loop...  you do it only once outside all loops !

Thus when the 2nd loop on number_x_1 starts, number_x_2 is already at the maximum value and the inside loop (at `while (number_x_2 < 1000)`) does not start.

Answer (score 0):

> Check that simple mistake.. you must initialize number_x_2 = 100 in outer loop..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


 int is_a_palindrome(int test_number);

int main (void)  
{
   long     result;
   long     number_x_1;
   long     number_x_2;
   long    biggest_pal;

  number_x_1 = 100;

  while (number_x_1 < 1000)
  {
        number_x_2 = 100;
        while (number_x_2 < 1000)
        {
           result = number_x_1 * number_x_2;
           printf("%li\n", result);
           if (is_a_palindrome(result) == 1)
           {
               biggest_pal = result;
               printf("palindrome found : %li", biggest_pal);
           }
        number_x_2++;
        }
    number_x_1++;
  }
return (biggest_pal);
}

int is_a_palindrome(int test_number)
{
  int test_number_unchanged;
  int reverse;

  reverse = 0;
  test_number_unchanged = test_number;

  while (test_number != 0)
  {
    reverse = reverse * 10;
    reverse = reverse + test_number % 10;
    test_number = test_number / 10;
  }

  if (test_number_unchanged == reverse)
  {
      return (1);
  }
  else
  {
      return (0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner while loop sends `number_x_2` to 1000, but then it stays at 1000 so the program never runs through the inner loop after the first cycle. The program then increments `number_x_1` until it reaches 1000, and the program ends.

To solve this, move the statement `number_x_2 = 100;` To the line before `while(number_x_2 < 1000)`.